# is a temporary l-value or not?

Tags: c++

Why does the first line in main compiles but the second doesn't?
Both are temporaries I think but one is treated as l-value and the other not..

```
class complex
{
   public:
     complex() : r(0),i(0) {}
     complex(double r_, double i_) : r(r_), i(i_)
    {

    }

  private:
    double r;
    double i;
 };

int main()
{
   complex(2,2) = complex(1,2);
   char() = char(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On class types, the assignment operator is a member function. That is, `a = b` is just syntatic sugar for `a.operator=(b)`. And it is perfectly fine to call member functions on temporaries.

Please note that in C++, the term *lvalue* has nothing to do with the left-hand side of an assignment. As your example demonstrates, it is perfectly fine to assign to rvalues of class type. Also, there are lvalues which you cannot assign to, for example arrays and/or constants, especially string literals.

Comment: yes! I think this is the argument I was missing ...operator= can be called on rvalues but "assignment" cannot be done on rvalues

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create an assignment operator, the compiler will create one for you. This means that you create two temporaries, and assign one to the other, then they are both discarded.

Comment: I don't see relevance to the question!

Answer (score 0):

No, the second is not a temporary. A temporary is something that has a (mostly limited) lifetime and has a region of storage it lives in for its period of life.

A `char()` has neither of these. Therefor, such expressions are forbidden to be assigned. It would not be clear what the assignment modifies from a language point of view. Will afterwards  `2` equal `0`?